# EJS - Or (||) Operator in If Statement is Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ejs

I'm making a navbar, which I want to display "Login" if the currentUser is null OR "1". EJS doesn't seem to like the || operator in if statements. I put the exact if statement in my app.js file, and it gets triggered for either condition.

```
                    <%if(currentUser != null || currentUser != "1"){%>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <%=currentUser%>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <%} else if(currentUser==1 || currentUser==null){%>
                <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Login</a>
                    </li>
                <%}%>
```

There's the code from the EJS file. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with EJS but I'm pretty sure you want to use && in the first if statement.

Comment: I want to check if either is true. Not both.

Comment: What is value of currentUser before first if statement?

Comment: But at least one of them will always be true 100% of the time.

Comment: It's either "1" or null.

Comment: && checks if BOTH are true. I want to check if either is true.

Comment: No, you want to check if both are true in the first one. Otherwise it's logically impossible for the result to be false.

Comment: If you *really* want to use ||, you need to do `!(currentUser == null || currentUser == "1")` instead.

Comment: So you want me to do: if(currentUser != null && currentUser != "1")?

Comment: When `currentUser = "1"`, then it's not `null`, so it passes. When `currentUser = null`, then it's not `"1"`, so it passes. There is no way for that logic to ever evaluate to `false`.